# Str_detect multiple columns using across

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a new column based on the results of `str_detect` across multiple columns using `across`.

For example, in the test data below, I'd like to search for "No job" across columns that start with "job", then return 1 if that string is detected in any of the columns, and 0 if it is not.

```
test_data <-  data.frame("job1" = c('Sales','Baker','Blacksmith','Brewer'), 
                         "job2" = c('Mailman','Jockey','Jobhunter',"No job"),
                         "id" = c("id_1", "id_2", "id_3", "id_4"))

# Output I'd like:

#         job1      job2   id no_job
#1      Sales   Mailman id_1      0
#2      Baker    Jockey id_2      0
#3 Blacksmith Jobhunter id_3      0
#4     Brewer    No job id_4      1
```

I know I could `unite` the columns that start with "job", and then just use `str_detect` on that new column like this:

```
test_data2 <- test_data %>%
    unite(col = "all_jobs", starts_with("job"), sep = ", ", remove = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(no_job = if_else(str_detect(all_jobs, "No job"), 1, 0))
```

... but I was wondering if there was a way to use `across` to do the same thing. I'd tried variations on the following but haven't gotten it to work.

```
test_data2 <- test_data %>%
    mutate(no_job = if_else(across(starts_with("job"), str_detect(., "No job")), 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option could be:

```
test_data %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(no_job = +any(str_detect(c_across(-id), "No job")))

  job1       job2      id    no_job
  <fct>      <fct>     <fct>  <int>
1 Sales      Mailman   id_1       0
2 Baker      Jockey    id_2       0
3 Blacksmith Jobhunter id_3       0
4 Brewer     No job    id_4       1
```

Comment: In case "No job" appears in multiple columns, you could use `mutate(no_job = as.numeric(any(str_detect(c_across(-id), "No job"))))`

Comment: What's the deal with the `+` ther in that `mutate()`? Could you please explain? I have never encountered that before, and I am very curious!!

Comment: @Dunois it is the same as `as.numeric()`, i.e. it just converts a logical vector to a numerical one.

Comment: @Dunois, is there a way to apply this to specific columns? I have a larger dataset and I would just like to apply this for specific columns.

Comment: @flxflks I'm not the OP, but in general, you can use selection verbs like `starts_with()` inside `c_across()` to specify a subset of columns. Or even more generally, you could just use `across()` within `mutate()`.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem and this is a possible solution using `case_when`:

```
test_data %>% mutate(no_job = case_when(if_any(str_detect(starts_with("job"), "No job"))~1))
```